# Does an Ethereum Node need to be accessible from the internet?

Tags: nodes, network

Suppose I want an Ethereum/BSC node running on my network using GETH.  I want to be able to access the node and run any sort of API calls against via Web3 from a locally running software.

The node has outbound access to the internet.

Does the node, in order to function properly, need to be accessible for inbound connections from the internet?

Answer (score 0):

Of course, your node needs to accessible from other nodes. If not, then how to get new blocks?

But this doesn't mean you have to open an RPC endpoint to all of the world. You can restrict access to your RPC endpoint with a firewall or something like that. This doesn't affect your node. Because nodes are communicating with each other using another port.